# How to get the global state in an action creator in react-native and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have successfully logged in my user using JWT with a rails backend. And have stored the `user` object in the global store for my react-native app using Redux and Redux-thunk.

However, I now need to access the `state.user.authentication_token` inside my other actions where I need to do a backend `fetch` request to get my data with the appropriate header have the authorised tokens.

Here is my AssetList.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchAssets } from '../actions';

class AssetsList extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchAssets();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Asset name...</Text>
        <Text>Asset name...</Text>
        <Text>Asset name...</Text>
        <Text>Asset name...</Text>
        <Text>Asset name...</Text>
        <Text>Asset name...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { fetchAssets })(AssetsList);
```

And here is my Action file which dispatches the action:

```
/*global fetch:false*/
import { API_ENDPOINT } from './api';

export const fetchAssets = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/assets`, {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-User-Token': 'ztUUQuxsnFKhYf8JMLKY', // I need access the user state here 
        'X-User-Email': 'somecoolemail@gmail.com' // AND HERE...
      }
    }).then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_SUCCESSFUL'
      });
      response.json().then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }).catch(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };
};
```

I need to access the user object from the state and replace the headers in the `fetch` request for the `X-User-Token` and the `X-User-Email` with the one stored in the state with the user object. However, I am not able to access my state inside the action file.

What am I missing here? How do I access the state in other files globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used redux in a little while, but this sounds like a perfect situation for a `thunk`.

**EDIT 1** - rereading your question, appears you already are. So just pass in a second param, which will be the function `getState`.

```
export const fetchAssets = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { user } = getState();
    // user.token == token

    // .. rest
  };
}
```

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk
http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

**EDIT 2**

Not specific to your question, and I will make a huge assumption here, but is your token actually part of state - I mean should it be? Unless the application changes it, it doesn't *need* to be part of your store. Don't fall into the common trap of thinking everything has to be in the redux store.

Comment: You sir... Are my hero of the day. :) Regarding your edit 2 : If I dont keep my token in the state, where do I keep it then? I should all the important bits should be kept in the global state? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: No worries - if the primary part of my answer helped, feel free to accept it so future readers can see the outcome. Regarding edit2 - its hugely subjective and app dependent, but config items (that don't change) can usually be simply imported as a plain old javascript object. For example, if you were using laravel, it stores request forgery tokens in the a head meta tag - so I construct a simple js object reading in all config items, and export it so any module can import and use the config items

Comment: The funny thing is, I am able to access the other state parts of my auth such as my username and password, however, the token is coming as undefined... Oh well, Debug mode on.

Comment: If you get stuck with reading in the token, feel free to link to another question

Comment: @Chris Regarding edit2 - I am also storing User Info in redux state which is not supposed to be stored in there. Now I am going to change it to simple js object. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Sometimes it should belong there, just depends on your app